# Регулярное выражение для поиска последней цифры в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как захватить последнюю цифру (одну) в строке?
Вот строка:
"00.00.00**1**_" или "00.00.001**1**" из нее мне нужна последняя цифра "1" (к примеру)

Пробовал `/\d?$/` и `/\d?_/`  но эти варианты подходят только для одной из строк.
Если четко сформулировать задачу, то мне нужно получить последнюю цифру, состоящую из одного символа, из строки.

Comment: На каком языке пишете код?

Comment: На javaScript. Не указывал язык, поскольку регулярки везде одинаковые.

Comment: @mboma, нет, отличаются.

Comment: И [ещё как отличаются](https://regex101.com/r/Z9zSPz/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать два подхода.

Первый: найти цифру, после которой нет цифр до конца строки.

```
/\d(?=\D*$)/
```

См. [демо регулярки](https://regex101.com/r/Az5Ekb/1).

- `\d`  - одна цифра
- `(?=\D*$)` - блок просмотра вперёд, проверяющий наличие 0+ символов, отличных от цифр (`\D*`), до конца строки (`$`)

Либо найти последнюю цифру с помощью захватывающей группы:

```
/.*(\d)/
```

См. [демо №2](https://regex101.com/r/Az5Ekb/2)

*Если в строке есть символы переводы строки, `.` замените на `[\s\S]`.*

Пример на JavaScript:

```js
var input = "00.00.001_";
var res = input.match(/\d(?=\D*$)/) || [];
console.log(res[0]);

input = "00.00.0012";
res = input.match(/.*(\d)/) || ['',''];
console.log(res[1]);
```

Comment: Ваше выражение рабочее, но в вопросе речь не шла о JS

Comment: Спасибо, шикарный ответ!

Comment: @mboma: Пожалуйста, если мой ответ помог вам решить проблему, отметьте ответ как решение (см. [*Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).